# FluentAssertions System.FormatException (possible bug)

Tags: c#, guid, fluent-assertions

I've been having some trouble with FluentAssertions lately, and after playing around with it a little bit, it seems like there is some sort of bug that may have something to do with `Guid`s. Here's the code that throws an error:

```
    class Dto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }



    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTest()
    {
        var dto1 =
            new List<Dto>
            {
                new Dto { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Name" }
            };
        var dto2 =
            new List<Dto>
            {
                new Dto { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Name" }
            };
        var list1 = new List<List<Dto>> { dto1, dto2 };
        var list2 = new List<List<Dto>> { dto2, dto1 };
        list1.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(list2);
    }
```

Note the reversed order in `list1` and `list2`, which is essential to reproduce the error:

> **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.**
>   Result StackTrace:
>   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
>      at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
>      at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
>      at FluentAssertions.Execution.MessageBuilder.FormatArgumentPlaceholders(String failureMessage, Object[] failureArgs) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Execution\MessageBuilder.cs:line 66
>      at FluentAssertions.Execution.MessageBuilder.Build(String message, Object[] messageArgs, String reason, ContextDataItems contextData) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Execution\MessageBuilder.cs:line 39
>      at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(String message, Object[] args) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Execution\AssertionScope.cs:line 190
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.LooselyMatchAgainst[T](IList`1 subjects, Object expectation, Int32 expectationIndex) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.cs:line 123
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.AssertElementGraphEquivalency[T](T[] subjects, Object[] expectations) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.cs:line 79
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.Execute[T](T[] subject, Object[] expectation) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.cs:line 39
>      at lambda_method(Closure )
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.GenericEnumerableEquivalencyStep.Handle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator parent, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\GenericEnumerableEquivalencyStep.cs:line 61
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EquivalencyValidator.AssertEqualityUsing(IEquivalencyValidationContext context) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EquivalencyValidator.cs:line 63
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.TryToMatch[T](T subject, Object expectation, Int32 expectationIndex) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.cs:line 133
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.LooselyMatchAgainst[T](IList`1 subjects, Object expectation, Int32 expectationIndex) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.cs:line 106
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.AssertElementGraphEquivalency[T](T[] subjects, Object[] expectations) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.cs:line 79
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.Execute[T](T[] subject, Object[] expectation) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EnumerableEquivalencyValidator.cs:line 39
>      at lambda_method(Closure )
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.GenericEnumerableEquivalencyStep.Handle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator parent, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\GenericEnumerableEquivalencyStep.cs:line 61
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EquivalencyValidator.AssertEqualityUsing(IEquivalencyValidationContext context) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EquivalencyValidator.cs:line 63
>      at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EquivalencyValidator.AssertEquality(EquivalencyValidationContext context) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Core\Equivalency\EquivalencyValidator.cs:line 35
>      at FluentAssertions.AssertionExtensions.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo[T](IEnumerable`1 subject, IEnumerable expectation, Func`2 config, String because, Object[] becauseArgs) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Shared\AssertionExtensions.cs:line 680
>      at FluentAssertions.AssertionExtensions.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo[T](IEnumerable`1 subject, IEnumerable expectation, String because, Object[] becauseArgs) in C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\Shared\AssertionExtensions.cs:line 637
>      at (Where my code is)

Sorry for the long stack trace, but I wanted to include anything that might be relevant.

What's going on here? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: For reference: http://fluentassertions.com/documentation.html#collections-and-dictionaries

Comment: Does it work without using `Guid`? Given that the exception is being thrown by a string formatter trying to format a failure message, I suspect that the failure message is appending the guid as a string (e.g. `{25afc5e0-6fbb-4762-a357-562d8a464c78}`, which gets interpreted as a formatting placeholder

Comment: @DStanley The error doesn't occur when I use `short`, for instance. That seems like a good interpretation of what's happening.

Comment: Gvien that the [author is on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253961/dennis-doomen) you might get a direct answer; in the meantime you can [report an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues)

Comment: I will! Just wanted to make sure this was an actual bug and not just something I didn't understand correctly.

Comment: @yinnonsanders I was able to reproduce the error even comparing dto1 to dto2

Comment: @Nkosi Interesting. Although that's not quite as bad because `dto1` and `dto2` are not equivalent, but FluentAssertions should give a helpful error message.

Comment: @yinnonsanders yes, strange indeed. Just thought I'd mention that so it could be included when you raise the issue with the author.

Comment: Yep. Definitely a bug. If you're willing to file a bug, it shouldn't take long to fix that.